# CKEDITOR PillowBackend Django disable thumbnail creation

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

By default, when inserting an image from the clipboard into the CKEDITOR editor, the images are saved in PNG format and take up a lot of disk space. I have enabled PillowBackend to be able to save images in JPG format, but its thumbnail is created along with the image, how can I disable thumbnail creation?

Or maybe there is a way when inserting an image from the clipboard into the CKEDITOR editor, you can save the image in JPG format without enabling PillowBackend, so that there is no thumbnail creation?

Comment: I'm using Django 3.2 and CKEditor 4.18.0 (django-ckeditor 6.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been sorted out, it is necessary in the venv/Lib/site-packages/ckeditor_uploader/backends/pillow_backend.py comment:

```
# if not animated:
#     self.create_thumbnail(file object, saved path)
```

I don't know how much is correct, but it works.